# Can't see android app icon in apps menu on device after deploying it

Tags: android

I made an android app and I want to deploy it on a device i.e my phone which is a Sony xperia S. The miniSdkVersion of the app is 15. The app is installed on the device but I can't see the icon on the apps menu of my phone.
Here is the manifest file.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.toshiba.ticketing"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />

<application
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
     <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
     <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
   <activity
        android:name=".Choose"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main_activity2" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TaskChoose"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_task_choose" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TicketChoose"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_ticket_choose" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".login"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|orientation|screenSize"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <data
                android:host="redirecturi"
                android:scheme="your" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ListAll"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_list_all" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ListInProgress"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_list_in_progress" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ListPending"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_list_pending" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TicketOverview"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_ticket_overview" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Map"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_map" >
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
    <activity
        android:name=".TicketList2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_ticket_list2" >
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: post manifest source

Comment: @SachinGutte I edited the post

Comment: Just a shot in the dark. Can you make sure your icon in drawable is compatible? Your icons should be in mipmap* folders..

Comment: I put the image in the mipmap folder but stil nothing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your device API level. If you have updated to KitKat (19) or higher, then the problem is the `android:maxSdkVersion="18"` entry in your manifest, and you should remove it.

From [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html):

> If the application's `maxSdkVersion` attribute is lower than the API Level
>   used by the system itself, then the system will not allow the application
>   to be installed.

Also it says:

> **Warning**: Declaring this attribute is not recommended.

Comment: Thanks. But in fact the app is well installed and I can test it with the device but it does not show the app on the apps menu of the device

Comment: I solved this by changing my minSdkVersion to 8 and targetSdkVersion to 18. Thanks All